# How to Login to Report Server 2016

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to wrap my head around the SSRS login. Here is my test setup.
SSRS 2016 installed on hostname: Testrs16
ReportServer Database installed on hostname: Server2
I'm launching ReportBuilder on Server2 and trying to connect and login to the report server (see screenshot). What login it typically used in this case? Thanks!

[ssrs login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmuGy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Authentication to your Report Server database is configured via the Report Server Configuration Manager. This will be the same for all users connecting to the Report Server.

***Note:** This is not the source of your data in your reports, but is where SSRS stores catalog information, user settings, and other internal components*

[Authentication Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-windows-authentication-on-the-report-server) for users connecting to the portal, web api, or soap endpoints are defined in your RSReportServer.config file as either RSWindowsNTLM (default), RSWindowsNegotiate, RSWindowsBasic, or Custom.

Once the user is authenticated *(who are they?)*, then the authorization *(what can they do)* is defined in the [folder management for catalog item security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/grant-user-access-to-a-report-server#to-add-a-user-or-group-to-an-item-role) by assigning roles to users or groups.

The other authentication that is required for rendering a report is authenticating to your report's data source. This is defined in either the Report's Data Source or in a Shared Data Source. Either of these can be configured in the data source management page on the portal.